# ElasticSearch not starting properly

Tags: elasticsearch, startup, kibana, sharding

On startup, our ElasticSearch server throws aJava exception I can see in the elasticsearch.log:

```
[2019-02-27T15:51:59,908][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [KibjtLy] [gc][young][263][19] duration [4.1s], collections [1]/[4.4s], total [4.1s]/[19.7s], memory [653.8mb]->[418.6mb]/[1.9gb], all_pools {[young] [258.7mb]->[1.6mb]/[266.2mb]}{[survivor] [25.9mb]->[30.7mb]/[33.2mb]}{[old] [369.1mb]->[386.2mb]/[1.6gb]}
[2019-02-27T15:51:59,909][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [KibjtLy] [gc][263] overhead, spent [4.1s] collecting in the last [4.4s]
[2019-02-27T15:52:01,928][WARN ][r.suppressed             ] path: /.kibana/doc/config%3A6.2.1, params: {index=.kibana, id=config:6.2.1, type=doc}
org.elasticsearch.action.NoShardAvailableActionException: No shard available for [get [.kibana][doc][config:6.2.1]: routing [null]]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.shard.TransportSingleShardAction$AsyncSingleAction.perform(TransportSingleShardAction.java:209) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.shard.TransportSingleShardAction$AsyncSingleAction.start(TransportSingleShardAction.java:186) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.shard.TransportSingleShardAction.doExecute(TransportSingleShardAction.java:95) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.shard.TransportSingleShardAction.doExecute(TransportSingleShardAction.java:59) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.doExecute(TransportAction.java:143) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:167) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:139) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:81) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.executeLocally(NodeClient.java:83) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.doExecute(NodeClient.java:72) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:405) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.get(AbstractClient.java:497) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.rest.action.document.RestGetAction.lambda$prepareRequest$0(RestGetAction.java:81) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.rest.BaseRestHandler.handleRequest(BaseRestHandler.java:97) [elasticsearch-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.dispatchRequest(RestController.java:240) [elasticsearch-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.tryAllHandlers(RestController.java:336) [elasticsearch-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.dispatchRequest(RestController.java:174) [elasticsearch-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.Netty4HttpServerTransport.dispatchRequest(Netty4HttpServerTransport.java:500) [transport-netty4-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.Netty4HttpRequestHandler.channelRead0(Netty4HttpRequestHandler.java:80) [transport-netty4-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.pipelining.HttpPipeliningHandler.channelRead(HttpPipeliningHandler.java:68) [transport-netty4-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102) [netty-codec-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.channelRead(MessageToMessageCodec.java:111) [netty-codec-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102) [netty-codec-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102) [netty-codec-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310) [netty-codec-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:284) [netty-codec-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286) [netty-handler-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1359) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:935) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:545) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:499) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459) [netty-transport-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) [netty-common-4.1.16.Final.jar:4.1.16.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_102]
[2019-02-27T15:52:14,740][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [KibjtLy] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards started [[filebeat-2019.02.27][2], [.kibana][0]] ...]).
[2019-02-27T15:53:51,192][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [KibjtLy] [gc][374] overhead, spent [691ms] collecting in the last [1s]
[2019-02-27T15:55:44,643][INFO ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [KibjtLy] [gc][487] overhead, spent [448ms] collecting in the last [1.3s]
```

The disk partition was almost full, which may have somehow started the problem, but now that the partition has been made larger, the problem remains.

We are using ElasticSearch 6.2.1 with OpenJDK 1.8.0_12, running on CentOS 7.3 (3.10.0-514 linux kernel).

Do you know how to solve that issue?

Comment: There is a problem with your .kibana index. Only Kibana config stuff is stored in the index. Is it possible to delete the .kibana index? If no .kibana index is present kibana will create one after restart. .kibana index includes alos dashboards an saved searches if you have one.

Comment: We have a whole lot of elaborate dashboards. If I could find a solution without deleting them, it really would be much better...

Comment: Are you sure you node is down? 1. There is no error only a warning 2. The last lines Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [YELLOW]. Try to connect to your node.

Comment: My Kibana reports display old data from before we had the disk space problem. But no new data coming from Logstash is indexed.

Comment: The kibana index has nothing todo with logstash. Can you check the logstash log files? Maybe set the log level to debug for more information, logstash can tell you whats going on. The warning from elasticsearch is only for .kibana, so if you lucky your filebeat indices are healthy. Can you connect with curl https://localhost:9200? If this will work, you node is theoretical ready for input.  Do you've snapshots? You can delete the .kibana index and restore it from snapshot.